# broken encrypted files after reformat

Tags: windows, encryption, ntfs, fat32, efs

I had some files encrypted with cipher cmd command on an external hard drive with FAT32 format. one day I had to copy a large file on that hard drive and I reformated the hard drive to NTFS format. after I reformated the hard drive my encrypted files were somehow broken. the result was my files got a *.pfile extension and a $EFS file was created in each folder and they are no longer encrypted. anyone have any idea what should I do to get my files up and running again?

Comment: That's odd. EFS stores keys in the SID (Windows authentication database), either locally or on a domain controller. What can you tell us about this "cipher cmd command" that you used, and you didn't actually reinstall Windows in the interim did you?

Comment: [View and use files that have been protected by Rights Management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/rms-client/sharing-app-view-use-files) might be relevant.

Comment: Hello, I just simply used cipher /e /s:[Path_name] for encrypting the files. and didn't reinstall the windows, if you are curious about the certificate key I have a backup of that key, I was using the external hard on two computers and it was working just fine  until the day I reformatted the hard drive using "convert c: /fs:ntfs" command then I saw my files have the ".pfile" extension and in each folder I was seeing an $EFS simple file @MichaelKjörling

Comment: @Seth I have tried it but its no good.

Comment: `cipher` shouldn't even work on FAT32 (`Displays or alters the encryption of directories [files] on NTFS partitions.`) Why would your external hard drive have the drive letter C:? Are you still able to use the file or are they actually encrypted? Did you try to decrypt a single file using the `/D` switch? Does it work?

Comment: "C:" was an example, I know it shouldn't work but it did. the actual problem is that the files are corrupted somehow. yes, I had tried using the /d switch but the problem is, after conversion the system doesn't know that the files were encrypted it just thinks that the files are not readable (*.pfile(s)). @Seth

Comment: A really, really bad one. But as it is you probably just lost your files. You used a tool in an unsupported scenario and ran a second command that greatly influences the structure of the data on a device. The best option would probably to restore from a backup. The `pfile` extension would hint at a different encryption and [`$EFS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypting_File_System) would be the ADS. If you see that now ... did you by chance convert from NTFS TO FAT32 instead of the other way around?

Comment: @seth I really appreciate your response but there is now way to turn `NTFS` to `FAT32` without loosing your data.

Comment: Just like you can't run `cipher` on FAT32 volumes, yes. So you will have to figure out what you actually did to those files or restore from a backup. Best of luck.